# target="_blank" vs. target="_new"

Tags: html

What's the difference between `<a target="_new">` and `<a target="_blank">` and which should I use if I just want to open a link in a new tab/window?

Comment: Summary of current anwsers: `_new` doesn't have any special meaning. You could write `_white_little_lamb` as well.

Comment: @x3ro How does that make it wrong to say that "`_new`" doesn't have any special meaning?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I was referring to "You could write ... instead". But thinking about it, I'd argue that "has no special meaning" is not the same as "is explicitly discouraged", but that might be me nitpicking ;)

Comment: I would like to remind everyone that using `target="_blank"` without `rel="noopener"` is a potential security vulnerability. Search for `rel="noopener"` to learn more.

Answer (score 689, accepted):

## Use "_blank"

According to the [HTML5 Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html):

> A **valid browsing context name** is any string with at least one character that does not start with a U+005F LOW LINE character. (Names starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)
>
> A **valid browsing context name or keyword** is any string that is either a valid browsing context name or that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of: _blank, _self, _parent, or _top." - [Source](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#browsing-context-names)

That means that there is no such keyword as `_new` in HTML5, and [not in HTML4 (and consequently XHTML) either](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-frame-target). That means, that there will be no consistent behavior whatsoever if you use this as a value for the target attribute.

#### Security recommendation

As Daniel and Michael have pointed out in the comments, when using target `_blank` pointing to an untrusted website, you should, in addition, set `rel="noopener"`. This prevents the opening site to mess with the opener via JavaScript. See [this post](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) for more information.

Comment: Leaving out the bolded text from the spec makes that quote sound confusingly circular. I read it as "A `valid browsing context name` or keyword is any string that is either a `valid browsing context name` or ...."

Comment: Guess you're right. But my understanding is, that **browsing context name** refers to frame names, etc.

Comment: @lyoshenka, @x3ro: I took the liberty to add the previous paragraph to the quote. That should clear up the confusion.

Comment: From the HTML 4 link: «Except for the reserved names listed below, frame target names [...] must begin with an alphabetic character (a-zA-Z). **User agents should ignore all other target names.**»—I don't know if they do that in practice. (The HTML 5 spec doesn't seem to provide explicit instructions for invalid names.)

Comment: @qarma Do you know of a resource that sums up the behaviour of popular browsers?

Comment: I wish. I searched and failed. AFAIK desktop browsers support it, I can't vouch for Android/iOS/etc.

Comment: "_new" means "name that window _new and load content", where "_blank" means "create a new window each time and load content". So, if you use "_blank" you get **multiple windows**, qtty of clicks = qtty of windows.
I have a case where I wanted to load different contents in a new window, if I use "_blank" I get a new window each time I click a link with "_blank" target, if I use a custom name "my_custom_name", each click in a link it will load in the **same** window, named "my_custom_name", no repeated windows. So, "_new" or "_whatever" are valid too. See http://jsfiddle.net/ALMH6/1/

Comment: @aesede: Read the spec. They are _not_ valid, because "my_custom_name" may not be prefixed with an underscore. Thus "new" would be fine, but "_new" is not!

Comment: @x3ro I agree on that, but as on many cases in HTML there are "invalid" things that the browsers tend to allow, like this case. Whoever had the idea of using for the first time "_new" maybe thought that using an underscore would follow the logic of the reserved words (_blank, _parent, etc) as it tries to have a **semantic** use: _new means "this is not just a named target for a frame, nor a reserved functionality, this means open a new, unique window". Again, I agree the underscore is invalid.

Comment: Securitywise this is an important read http://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Comment: There is no ! in the end "_blank"... ☺

Comment: Please consider adding that people should also add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` due to [javascript attack vulnerability](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/) of `target="_blank"`

Comment: those ancient nonstandard bits seem to stick forever. this is another mistake that can [force a html5 page into compatibility mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584514/1132334) in IE. I just fixed it in one of my projects, had 17 occurrences, and I strongly recommend to use full text search and a service like https://validator.w3.org to get rid of those vestiges from the previous century. where can I upvote your username?

Comment: Per the [linked post](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) - "2021 update: Browsers now implicitly set `rel="noopener"` for any `target="_blank"` link, [following a spec change](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4078)."

Answer (score 139):

Using `target="_blank"` will instruct the browser to create a new browser tab or window when the user clicks on the link.

Using `target="_new"` is technically invalid according to the specifications, but as far as I know every browser will behave the same way:

- it will search for a tab or window with the context name "_new"
- if a "_new" tab/window is found, then the URL is loaded into it
- if it's not found, a new tab/window is created with the context name "_new", and the URL loaded into it

Note `target="_new"` will behave exactly the same as `target="new"`, and the latter is valid HTML while the former is invalid HTML.

Adding some confusion to this, in HTML4 the `target` attribute was deprecated. In HTML5 this decision was reversed, and it is an official part of the spec once again. All browsers support `target` no matter what version of HTML you are using, but some validators will flag the use as deprecated if your doctype is HTML4.

Comment: So, basically, if I have two (or more) links with `target="_new"`, they both will open in the same tab, one overwriting the other?

Comment: @art-solopov as far as I know, yes that is what will happen in every browser. However "_new" is an illegal value for a target so don't do it.

Answer (score 27):

I know this is an old question and the correct answer, use `_blank`, has been mentioned several times, but using `<a target="somesite.com" target="_blank">Link</a>` **is a security risk**.

It is [recommended](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) ([performance benefits](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/performance-benefits-of-rel-noopener/)) to use:

```
<a href="somesite.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link</a>
```

Comment: Just some additional reading on the security risk aspect: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/

Answer (score 15):

This may have been asked before but:

"every link that specifies target="_new" looks for and finds that window by name, and opens in it.

If you use target="_blank," a brand new window will be created each time, on top of the current window."

from here: http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000316.html

Answer (score 14):

it's my understanding that `target = whatever` will look for a frame/window with that name. If not found, it will open up a new window with that name. If `whatever == "_new"`, it will appear just as if you used `_blank` except.....

Using one of the reserved target names will bypass the "looking" phase.  So, `target = "_blank"` on a dozen links will open up a dozen blank windows, but `target = whatever` on a dozen links will only open up one window. `target = "_new"` on a dozen links may give inconstant behavior.  I haven't tried it on several browsers, but should only open up one window.

At least this is how I interpret the rules.

Answer (score 13):

`target="_blank"` opens a new tab in most browsers.

Answer (score 11):

Caution - remember to always include the "quotes" - at least on Chrome, `target=_blank` (no quotes) is NOT THE SAME as `target="_blank"` (with quotes).

The latter opens each link in a new tab/window.  The former (missing quotes) opens the first link you click in one new tab/window, then overwrites that same tab/window with each subsequent link you click (that's named also with the missing quotes).

Comment: Very good point.  I ran into this issue when I didn't enclose the _blank in quotes.  The link I clicked on from my newly created "blank" tab was over writing content within that tab instead of opening a new tab.  Enclosing the _blank in quotes forces chrome to open a new tab every time.

Comment: Also, make sure to use "_blank" not "_BLANK".  Chrome is actually fussy about case and won't open a new tab using "_BLANK" multiple times.

Comment: Not sure if this post is still relevant (I use FF, so I can't check), but if still true, this is a violation of the [spec for unquoted attribute values](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attribute-value-(unquoted)-state); Essentially, anything that isn't a greater-than sign or whitespace is an acceptable unquoted attribute value character (some may produce parse errors, however).

Answer (score 5):

- _blank as a target value will spawn a new window every time,
- _new will only spawn one new window.

Also, every link clicked with a target value of _new will replace the page loaded in the previously spawned window.

You can click here [When to use _blank or _new](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/when-not-to-use-target_blank-link-attribute/19924/) to try it out for yourself.

Comment: Can you list which browsers honour `_new` as described?

Comment: @qarma That behaviour is as described in all the browsers I know of, `_new` isn't a magical key word, it's just a name, if a window with that name exists it'll reuse it, otherwise it'll open it. Clicking multiple links for that window will just open different pages in the named window, rather than opening multiple new pages.

Comment: The spec actually suggests to browsers that they `ignore` targets that starts with underline but are not keywords.  There are no suggestions for what a browser should do when it "ignores" an invalid target name.  Possibilities include: (1) treat it like "_blank" (2) treat it like a window name (as if there wasn't an illegal underscore) (3) treat it like a explicitly empty window name (4) treat it like there was no target attribute.  -- Any browser could pick any of the interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute of a link forces the browser to open the destination page in a new browser window. Using `_blank` as a target value will spawn a new window every time while using `_new` will only spawn one new window and every link clicked with a target value of `_new` will replace the page loaded in the previously spawned window

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a link in a new tab/window you'll use `<a target="_blank">`.

value `_blank` = targeted browsing context: a new one: tab or window depending on your browsing settings

value `_new` = not valid; no such value in HTML5 for target attribute on a element

target attribute with all its values on a element: [video demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_attributes/a/html5_a_target_attribute.php)

Answer (score -2):

The use of _New is useful when working on pages that are Iframed. Since target="_blank" doesn't do the trick and opens the page on the same iframe... target new is the best solution for Iframe Pages. Just my five cents.