# How can I indicate that a popup has been blocked by Safari?

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

In Safari for iPad, if the popups are disabled, is there any way to get the bar at the top..like in IE which says "...website trying to open popup.."

I mean the user can at least come to know there is some popup being opened..

Otherwise if the popup setting is blocked, nothing happens when the user clicks on a link which has that popup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way that I know of to get a new window to open up in Mobile Safari is to use the `target="_blank"` (and I guess `target="_new"`) attribute.

```
<a href="my_popup_page.html" target="_blank">Open 'popup'</a>
```

Comment: Is there any other way and what will be the difference in behavior/browser output if I use  target="_blank" Vs window.open ?

Comment: In normal browsers, you'll have no control over things like showing/hiding the menu bar, address bar, and the size of the window.  And you also won't get a JS reference to the page that you opened.  But if you don't mess with those things anyway, it should behave similarly.

Comment: `target="_new"` shouldn't be used. Use `target="_blank"`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new#4964223