# window.open() doesn't work on safari ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

I have page with input field. Suppose user enters x there, then I need to open page/x.
My code is:

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="javascript:window.open('{% url 'index' %}'+this.days.value,'null');return false">
        <input type="number" name="days" autofocus  required><br>
    </form>
```

It works perfectly on my laptop but not on my iphone. When I enter number and press "Go" in safari nothing happens. 
How should I change it to make it work on Iphone? Maybe it's better to implement it different way? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't currently a way to open a new Safari window on iOS.

You may want to look at a similar Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649962/ipad-safari-popup). This will show you that you can use the following code to achieve a similar result:

```
<a href="my_popup_page.html" target="_blank">Open 'popup'</a>
```

Hope this helps!