# How can I open a link in new tab (and not new window)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an 'Open' button that 'calculates' a link that should be opened in a new tab.
I try to use:

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

But that opens a new window.

I also tried the following method:

```
<form id="oform" name="oform" action="" method="post" target="_blank">
</form>

...

document.getElementById("oform").action = url;
document.getElementById("oform").submit();
```

Still, a new window is opened, instead of a new tab.

When using simple `<a href...>` with `target='blank'`, the link is opened in a new tab.

Is there a solution?

Comment: In Chrome a `<form target="_blank">` opens in a new tab when submitted, so it depends on the browser.

Comment: i use chrome, and yet it opens in new window instead of new tab

Answer (score 69):

Update [**2019**] Most browsers today open in a new tab when you set the target to `_blank`. The days of popup windows is long gone. We can now use:

```
 <a href="some url" target="_blank">content of the anchor</a>
```

Most sane browsers will open the new window in a new tab.

---

<s>CSS3 supports "open in new tab", by the property [target-new](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/)</s>

```
target-new: window | tab | none;
```

Update [**2016**]: this method never made it into the CSS3 spec, as one of the comments indicates. This shouldn't be used. However, it can be seen that most modern browsers open `target='_blank'` links in a new tab anyway, unless one attempts to resize the new tab immediately thereafter. However, there does not appear to be a mechanism to force this behavior in the specifications.

---

[**2011**] For a method of forcing opening in a new tab that is well supported, try the following:

```
<a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>
```

---

Else, use [this](http://www.paulsilver.co.uk/code/html_working_popup.php) method to resize window immediately, to ensure that popup blockers do not kill your popup

Comment: not sure i understand how to use it

Comment: @Erik It will be a while before these browsers start supporting that. For now, all you can do is change the about:config in firefox, to force that behavior.

Comment: but how some sites manage to do that?

Comment: This supposedly works in firefox
<a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>

Comment: As i said in the main message, when using <a href=...> it works as a charm and the link is opened in a new tab.

Comment: Try this approach http://www.paulsilver.co.uk/code/html_working_popup.php

Comment: I have to agree with Kon, you are removing the choice from the user and should think carefully about that. Each user has his / her preference and their workflow enables said preference. Making this choice for them takes away their preference e.g. (middle-click becomes mute). However, I can think of some cases that this is desired e.g. dialogues, receipts, prints, etc.

Comment: `_newtab` works, yes, but it's not W3C compliant.

Comment: At this time, `_newtab` doesn't seem to work in Opera, which probably means it also doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this made it into CSS3 either; it's not mentioned in [W3C:s CSS Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/), nor in its [table over CSS3 browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp).

Comment: @TomasLycken It is not. The one linked in this answer is a very old [Working Draft (24 February 2004)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/). If you clicked on the [latest version (14 October 2014)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/) it says that "... The specification is no longer being developed"
  
With that said, I don't think we should use W3School as the _only_ source of truth.

Answer (score 9):

Other than the CSS3 target-new option @anirudh4444 mentioned, you can't and mostly importantly probably shouldn't. You are trying to control the user's experience, when this should most likely be left up to the user.

Comment: I know some sites in which clicking a 'Login' button opens a new tab

Comment: Does that make it right?

Comment: Many of the browsers block pop-ups. I want the link to be opened in new tab so it would not be blocked

Comment: I'm not sure that will stop it from being blocked.  There are pop-up blockers that also prevent new tabs from spawning.  Your best bet (taking user experience into consideration) is to do a lightbox/modal effect without trying to manipulate the physical browser window/tab collection.  That's just my two cents.

Comment: If you're worried about your window being "blocked", don't be. If a user clicks on a normal link, the browser will not block that window. If you are using Javascript to open this new link, then you might have a problem.

Comment: Than i have a problem :P. I do use javascript

Answer (score 7):

You can use any of the following, I tested them all in 6 different browsers. (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Internet Explorer, Opera, K-meleon* and Seamonkey.)

1. `<a href="blaah" target="_blank">Blaah</a>`
2. `<a href="blaah" target="_tab">Blaah</a>`
3. `<a href="blaah" target="_new">Blaah</a>`

They all work the exact same, and the choice is completely up to preference.

*K-meleon, for some reason just opened up the page I was on when I clicked the link.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4964223/18192 .  Though they might all work, `_blank` is recommended.

Comment: They might all work the first time you click such a link.  But the second time you click such a link, it might open a new tab or it might open that URL in the same tab it used the last time.  Only `target="_blank"` is defined to always use a new tab (or window if your browser is configured that way).

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue using a "form" element.

```
function openNewTab(link) {
     var frm = $('<form   method="get" action="' + link + '" target="_blank"></form>')
     $("body").append(frm);
     frm.submit().remove();
}
```

For complete implementation and details visit my post http://mukesh.in/force-open-new-tab-in-browsers-instead-of-windows/

Or see this  [JSFiddle](http://goo.gl/yd0yJK)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: first link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Your form has target="_blank" (including a leading underscore) while your simple link has the target='blank' without the leading underscore.  The "_blank" is a reserved word specifying a particular action, but "blank" is the name of a specific, possibly new, window.  That's why you're getting different results.  Both are pop-ups, but different types.

Each user has ultimate control about whether a pop-up should open a new window or a new tab.  There's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Chrome:

```
<script>
    function buildAndGo() {
        var aEl = document.getElementById('missingLink');
        aEl.href = "#" + resultOfSomeCalculation();

        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        e.initEvent( 'click', true, true );

        aEl.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
</script>
...
<button onclick="buildAndGo()">Do it</button>
<a href="#" id="missingLink" target="_blank" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
```

Working from the following sources to try and get an IE version working:
[Selenium BrowserBot](http://www.google.com/codesearch#2tHw6m3DZzo/trunk/common/src/js/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js&q=BrowserBot.prototype.triggerMouseEvent%20package%3ahttp://selenium%5C.googlecode%5C.com),
[YUI User Action](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/UserAction.js.html)

Answer (score -3):

In case of a link yes only using **target** tag would work.

But In case of a button try doing this with the **onclick** function instead of using just **_blank**

Use the window.open(url, target) function instead - it takes a URL, and a target window name, which behaves the same as the target="something" attribute on a link....like this

```
button(type="button", onclick="window.open('auth/google', '_blank');")
```

This should work.

Comment: `window.open(url, '_blank');` is exactly the code that the OP says doesn't work.