# Opening a new tab in JS

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to open a new tab in JS?? I tried googling it but most answers were answered before about  years that it was not possible then, so is it possible now?!

Thank in advance :))

another question if possible, can we open to separate Urls using the same  tag? I mean to open 2 diff tabs when clicking on one hyperlink

Comment: I edited your question and removed PHP as a tag, since PHP is a server-side language and has nothing to do with the browser behavior.

Comment: Thank you, we usually write them in pairs,that's so stupid of me lol :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. You could do this in Javascript using `window.open('target.html','mywindow','width=400,height=200')` added to the onclick event.
See [this for more](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm) info.

Comment: <a href="somewebsite.html" target="_blank">Link </a>

Comment: Okay, See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/javascript-how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window/6296060#6296060

Comment: Use this method at http://www.paulsilver.co.uk/code/html_working_popup.php, it works on several browsers

Comment: oh the same answer =) 
Thanksss alot though :) another question if possible, can we open to separate Urls using the same <a> tag? I mean to open 2 diff tabs when clicking on one hyperlink

Comment: You would have to use javascript. I made an example for you at http://jsfiddle.net/4r4gq/

Comment: wow! Thank you for the fast reply, the answer , and this new link =))))!

Comment: Sorry! I set the same window name just there! That would open both on the same window. I have corrected it... See http://jsfiddle.net/4r4gq/3/

Answer (score 2):

Opening a new tab in modern browsers is the same as opening a link in a new window by setting the target attribute. With HTML you do this by:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

(See [HTML a target attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp))

With javascript you do the same by window.open(url, '_blank'...) but **remember that most browsers will block this unless it is done on the onClick event, so opening a new tab automatically after some timer has gone off for example is not a good idea.**

Comment: Thank you!will take this into account!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `<a href="/target" target="_blank">link text</a>` if it's a link that should open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to open both pages at the same time you could always combine both of the techniques mentioned above.

```
<a href="thispage.html" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('thatpage.html');">Double Link</a>
```

This will open the pages `thispage.html` and `thatpage.html` simultaneously.

dont forget to add the `title` attribute to your link as opening new windows/tabs without warning users is generally frowned upon. Something like;

```
title="Clicking this link will open two new tabs"
```

should keep the standardistas off your back.

Also, you may want to separate your `onclick` event from your `html` as again munging them all together really isnt best practice. If you are using jquery  then assign the `onclick` event by inserting a small piece of JavaScript at the top of your page as such;

```
$(function(){
      $('#the-link-id').click(function(){
             window.open('thatpage.html');
      });
);
```