# Open new tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have this code which opens all links in my page in a new window:

```
<base target='_new' />
```

It works fine in Chrome but in IE(8) and Firefox not so. In Firefox it does open a new tab, but on a second link click it loads in the new tab but without putting this tab up front, so a user would have to click on the new tab manualy. In IE it opens a new browser window. Is there an equivalent code (..js/Jquery) to open in a new tab in all browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - how can i open a link in new tab (and not new window)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/javascript-how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window)

Comment: did you try with "_blank" instead of "_new"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's no guarantee where the browser will open that new window/tab. different browsers open new windows/tabs differently, and that behavior can also be affected by browser settings.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox has an option to switch to the tab immediately.

```
Tools -> Options -> Tabs, 
    "When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately"
```

IE9 has the same option

```
Tools -> Internet Options -> General -> Tabs Settings
    "Always switch to new tabs when they are created"
```

IE9 has the option of what to do with new popups.

```
Tools -> Internet Options -> General -> Tabs Settings
    "When a popup is encountered"
     - Let Internet Explorer decide ...
     - Always open popups in a new tab
     - Always open popups in a new window
```

From http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Tabbed-browsing-frequently-asked-questions

```
If you opt to let Internet Explorer decide how to display pop-ups, it 
will display the pop-up in a new window if the pop-up specifies size 
or display requirements. Otherwise, the pop-up is displayed in a new tab.
```

So the behavior is mostly left up to the user and not the developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not control this part (how to open - in tab or in window). Since this is decided by browser. More of that, you can not even rely on type of browser, since each user may select his or hers way to open new pages: always in tabs or always in new windows or some other way.

Comment: seeds default firefox keeps in original tab, whereas default chrome will use new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this applies with the "base" tag, but on links, the "target" attribute can either have one predefined keyword, or any name you want to give the new window.

The available keywords are:

- _blank: opens the links in a new window or tab
- _self: opens the links in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
- _parent: opens the links in the parent frame
- _top: opens the links in the full body of the window

(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

If you don't use one of those keywords, you can use any name you want and this name will then be used to refer to that window. This allows you to reuse a tab you opened to load a different document in it.

So by using "_new" (which is *not* a keyword) as the base target, you essentially say that all links must be opened in the window named "_new". At first this window does not exist, so the browser creates it (first click), and the it reuses it for all following clicks.

Use "_blank" instead so that each link opens in its own new tab.