# How can I force Chrome to open specified link in a new tab instead of in the same window with extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript - how can i open a link in new tab (and not new window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/javascript-how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window)

I'm writing a extension to give a options to users that forcing chrome to open AD links in new tabs instead of opening in the same window. I want to know if there is a way to do so without modifying "target = '_top'" in the  tag? Those AD links all are in iframes, I don't want to inject content script into all of those iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chrome.tabs.create(options)` to create a new tab in a Chrome extension.

Comment: What listener should I use to intercept the event of open link in the same window in order to prevent the default event, get the url and using chrome.tabs.create to create the new tab?