# Open an url in a new tab from a Jpanel inside a JApplet

Tags: java, swing, url, jpanel, japplet

So my Applet work like that :

The main .class is extended from `JApplet`, therefore it can be use as an applet.

This main class load other .class file to display new window, that are extented from JPanel.

This current set up work fine as an applet, however, in one of my `JPanel` class I have a button that open an URL. I use the Desktop API and it works fine on the browser, the problem is : It opens the URL in the same tab as the applet.

I would like the URL to open in a new tab from my `JPanel`. I know I can use something like  :

```
  AppletContext a = getAppletContext();
  URL url = new URL(link);
  a.showDocument(url,"_blank");
```

but the method `getAppletContext()` only work from a class that has extented JApplet, not a JPanel.

I have tried to change my `Jpanel` to a `JApplet` but that seems to create some kind of mess.

Any idea how I could achieve that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but two possibilities come to mind:

- Pass the `AppletContext` to your `JPanel` as a constructor parameter.
- Set the `target` attribute in the URL, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296060/230513).

Comment: Genius, I have to rethink the design of my applet but I'm pretty sure your first thought will work.

Thanks !