# I want to open a new tab instead of a popup window

Tags: javascript, php, html, tabs, popup

I am trying to open a new tab.
But `Window.open()` is opening up popup window.

I want to open `hello.php` file in a new tab.
But it is opening up in a new popup window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

document.onmousedown=disableclick;
//status="Right Click Disabled";

function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     //alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false">

<form action="" method="POST" oncontextmenu="return false">



<b>Enter Username:</b><input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br>

<b>Enter Password: </b><input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="reset" name="reset"/>

</form>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("demo") or die(mysql_error()); 

$result=mysql_query("select * from employees where name='$username' and pass='$password'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 


if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
{
print "<br/>";
print "<b>Incorrect Username/Password!!!</b>";
}
else
{


mysql_query("Create table $username(Question_No varchar(10),Selected_Answer varchar(10))") 
 or die(mysql_error());  


print "<br/>";
print "<b>Login successful!!!</b><br/><br/>";


print "<script>window.open('hello.php?username=$username')</script>";


print "<script>window.close('userdetails.php')</script>";
}

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a browser settings issue. You can't do this with code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case it could be a javascript issue about override functions, do that:

```
<script>
(function(window, undefined){
    var win = window.open('your_url', '_blank');
    win.focus();
})(window);
</script>
```

That should make you can't use functions from other javascript code out of your function(window, undefined) wrapper-

Comment: Yes, for sure you can use `window.opener` and it will give you the name of the window that opened this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `window.open(url, '_blank');`

Comment: Using `window.open` tells the browser to open something new and the browser opens up what is chosen in its settings - tab or window.

Comment: Will I be able to use `opener` inside this newly opened window?

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

assign the url to open to a  tag's href attribute, with target="_blank", then trigger link click when you want. Example:

```
<a id="myLink" href="hello.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" target="_blank">
```

Then, call a js function to trigger link click

```
document.getElementById('myLink').click();
```