# Functionality of window.open() in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am not a very experienced javascript programmer by any means, but I am trying to prototype something for design purposes and I need some help. Here are some questions I have about window.open() in chrome

1. How do I get the page to open in a new window. Not just another chrome tab.
2. Is it possible for me click a link in one window and have it open in some other window already open on my browser.
3. If I can open it in another window it is possible to specify which tab. Whether it be a tab that's already open or opening a new tab.

Thanks

Comment: For #1, [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Comment: 1. You can try, but you can't do it reliably, it's up to the users settings. 2 and 3. It's possible, if the window was opened by you. You can't access random tabs or windows that you didn't open in the same script.

Comment: Is there anyway you could elaborate on 3? I'm just wondering where I would need to specify which tab and window to open in

Comment: @PeterPaiste You can specify the name of a known window/tab with the 2nd argument to reuse it. `open()` doesn't support any more refined options than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to quote other answers from helpful posts that will go more in depth to what you need to know, all the answers here are in javascript:

1. [Open a URL in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)
   also
   [Open URL in New Window with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript)
2. [open url in new tab or reuse existing one whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779508/open-url-in-new-tab-or-reuse-existing-one-whenever-possible)
   also
   [I want to open a new tab instead of a popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098705/i-want-to-open-a-new-tab-instead-of-a-popup-window)
3. You cannot open new windows or new tabs that your Javascript does not already know about because its outside its scope.

I hope this helps, please feel free to comment if you need anything further!