# opening a new tab for a link url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to open a new TAB not a new window for a URL link.  I tried adding  target="_tab" put still a new window is opening and a new tab.  The new tab is saying LocalHost but it is not accessible.  The new window is having the proper URL link.

I don't understand why a new window is open.  Can we just have a new tab with the URL link ?

Here is the code:

```
  <div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt">
        <small>
          <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://maps.google.ca/maps?
              q=3100+ReneLevesque+Quebec&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=
              3100+ReneLevesque,+Quebec,+Qu%C3%A9bec+J4X+1C3&amp;t=m&amp;
              source=embed&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A')" style="color:#0000FF;
              text-align:end"  target="_tab" >Bigger Map </a>

       </small>
   </div>
```

MODIFY code   Still not working, ie it is opening a New Window not a TAB.

```
       <small>
          <a href="https://maps.google.ca/maps? 
          q=3100+ReneLevesque+Quebec&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=
          3100+ReneLevesque+Quebec,+Qu%C3%A9bec+J4X+1C3&amp;t=m&amp;source=embed&amp;
          z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;
          text-align:end" target="_blank"  >Bigger Map</a>

       </small>
```

Comment: I've seen some of your comments below about tab settings... what browser version (I know you're using IE) and OS are you using? Do you have any browser plugins or browser toolbars installed? Are you sure there is no other javascript firing when you click on the link?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `target="_blank"` instead of `target="_tab"`

Comment: I removed the href="#" and the onclick but still opening a new window  with _blank or _tab

Answer (score 1):

### 1 - Remove unwanted behaviour

Remove the javascript `onclick` event as it is not needed. It is also actually what is causing you to get a new window because you are calling `window.open`. This is eaxctly what you don't want. Copy the required url to the `href` attribute instead of `href="#"`.

### 2 - Set the target attribute

Change the `target` attribute of the `a` tag and set it to `_blank` which is a built in instruction to tell the browser to open the link in a new tab. In older browsers, `_blank` would open a new window (before tabbed browsers were around) but now all modern browsers will open a `_blank` link in a new tab by default.

It should look like this:

```
<a href="https://maps.google.ca/maps?
          q=3100+ReneLevesque+Quebec&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=
          3100+ReneLevesque,+Quebec,+Qu%C3%A9bec+J4X+1C3&amp;t=m&amp;
          source=embed&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" target="_blank" style="color:#0000FF;
          text-align:end" >Bigger Map </a>
```

#### Note

There are several built in `target` attributes:

- _blank
- _parent
- _self
- _ top

[Here's some documentation from Mozilla about the `target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> This attribute specifies where to display the linked resource.
>   In HTML4, this is the name of, or a keyword for, a frame. In HTML5, it
>   is a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (for example, tab,
>   window, or inline frame). The following keywords have special
>   meanings:
>
> **_self**: Load the response into the same HTML4 frame (or HTML5 browsing context) as the current one. This value is the default if the
>   attribute is not specified.
>
> **_blank**: Load the response into a new unnamed HTML4 window or HTML5 browsing context.
>
> **_parent**: Load the response into the HTML4 frameset parent of the current frame or HTML5 parent browsing context of the current one. If
>   there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.
>
> **_top**: In HTML4: Load the response into the full, original window, canceling all other frames. In HTML5: Load the response into the
>   top-level browsing context (that is, the browsing context that is an
>   ancestor of the current one, and has no parent). If there is no
>   parent, this option behaves the same way as _self. Use this attribute
>   only if the href attribute is present.

Any other string you use will give the target of the link a name and then you can use that elsewhere to open other links in the same tab. E.g. if you call it "dave" then it will open a new tab which the browser will know as "dave". Any other link with `target="dave"` will open in the tab the browser knows as "dave" - not a new tab.

Comment: Thanks - didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your href a bit:

```
  <a href="https://maps.google.ca/maps?
      q=3100+ReneLevesque+Quebec&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=
      3100+ReneLevesque,+Quebec,+Qu%C3%A9bec+J4X+1C3&amp;t=m&amp;
      source=embed&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;
      text-align:end"  target="_blank" >Bigger Map </a>
```

Comment: I removed the href="#" and the onclick but still opening a new window  with _blank or _tab

Comment: Looking at your modified code, you have an invalid target supplied. To open a new tab, you need to specify a target of `_blank`. See this link for href target specifications: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: I have made a fiddle that shows you the setup you need: http://jsfiddle.net/kGWLq/. This is code copied right out of my answer.

Comment: Brunnscheon  I tried _blank but it still opening a new window. I tried _tab and _newtab but same result as a new window is open each time instead of a tab.  I used the MODIFY code.  thanks for your help

Comment: I double check the code you put in jsfiddle and I have the exact same one.  But it open a new window.  I am using explorer

Comment: Have you made any changes to your browser settings that would make it always open a new window? See this link for browser settings associated with tabbed browsing: http://www.eightforums.com/browsers-mail/5643-ie10-browsing-always-opens-new-tabs.html. The link is for Windows 8, but it will point you towards what I think might be your problem.

Comment: I went to Internet options - general-TAb- Open links from other programs in:  I selected the The current tab or window.  I didn't fix the problem ie it still open a new window instead of a tab

Answer (score 0):

[How can I open a link in new tab (and not new window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window) this question is basically the same thing.

In short you can use the css property:

```
target-new:tab
```

However, the general recommendation is that you shouldn't try and control what the user is doing, leave it up to them and their browser.

Comment: This doesn't not resolve this issue.  I also tried _newtab but it is still opening a new window not a TAB

Answer (score 0):

```
@model WebTest.Models.Urls
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "URL shortener";
}

<h2>Shorten a URL</h2>
@Html.ValidationSummary()

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Url.Name, new { placeholder = "URL Shortened Name", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Url.UrlLink, new { placeholder = "URL Link", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Shorten" />
}

<table class="table full-width">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Url Shortened Name</th>
            <th>Url Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var url in Model.UrlList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="@(url.UrlLink)" target="_blank">@(url.Name)</a></td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => url.UrlLink)</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>    


[HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                MvcApplication.Log.Info("Hello");
                  Urls urls = new Urls();

                urls.UrlList = ReadURLToFile();
                //Url url = new Url();
                return View(urls);
            }

            public ActionResult Index(Url url)
            {
                Urls urls = new Urls();

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    urls.UrlList = ReadURLToFile();
                    AddURLToFile(urls,url);
                }
                return View(urls);
            }
```