# Open page using new tab in chrome by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome

I'm working on ASP.NET Webform along with C#. I'm trying to open up page in new tab using Window.open(url,"_blank"). It's working fine in Mozilla but in the chrome, It opens in new window.

Note : I'm calling window.open by using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript.

How to open this page using new tab in chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a link in new tab (and not new window)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is OK, but it will only open in a new tab if the action is triggered by the user otherwise chrome launches a new browser window. This behavior can be configured in chrome preferences. A example of this is the fiddle of Jordy, the example opens a new tab when you push the button "go!" but if you launch the code from chrome inspector's console it opens a new instance of the browser.

Comment: So, How to change chrome preferences?

Comment: sorry it looks like it's not an option anymore... anyway you can try to use these extensions but i'don't know if a client-side solution is an option for you... there you got the links.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-new-blank-in-new-bac/bblhflcbilbefagmeoanbdiofmmnehda

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/one-window/papnlnnbddhckngcblfljaelgceffobn

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Chrome (tested on Chrome for Mac 33.0.1750.146):

```
window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5F4C/

Comment: I'm trying to call it from PageLoad event of aspx.cs page.

Comment: Note: works only if used with onclick event. Opens a new window if called directly from JS.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window)

CSS3 supports "open in new tab":

```
target-new: window | tab | none;
```

The handling of "_blank" is up to the browser so you cannot guarantee that it will open in a new tab and not in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

In the page load event add the below:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open(url);</script>");
```