# Open in New Tab option is not available for GET Method Link/Submit button

Tags: php, forms

I have dynamic website pages that get products details from database by using GET Method. But problem is that user can't open products listings in new tab of browser. Its just open in same/current browser's tab as there is no option is available in right click menu as "Open in new tab". Any solution please?? 
Exp:

```
<form id="form" name="form" action='productdetails.php' method='GET'>
<input name="search" value="<?=$row['ID']?>" type="hidden"></input>
<input type="image" src="http://website.com/products/<?=$row['picture']?>.jpg"></input>
</form>
```

Now if someone click at image/picture, then "www.website.com/productdetails.php?search=proudcutid" will open in same browser tab. but if he make right click on image and try to open product listing in new tab, he can't as there is no option of "Open in new tab" in right click menu.
I don't want to use _blank as its always open in new browser tab that might be annoying users.
Check this link: http://www.shajam.net/msweaters.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a link in new tab (and not new window)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296013/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-new-tab-and-not-new-window)

Comment: <a href="productdetails.php?id=x" target="_blank">see details from </a> ?

Comment: use target="blank" in anchor tag

Comment: Please paste your code. Through which we can easily find your problem and help you ASAP.

Comment: Hi @Jamz : `open in new tab` will open in new tab. Not in new browser. `Open in new window` will open the details in new browser. So, what you want, when people click on image, it should go to new tab ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href "..." target = "_blank"></a>
```

The _blank will open up the targeted url in a new page

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Add , `onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">` for opening in new tab.

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Facebook" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
```

OR, simply add `target="_blank"` in `<a></a>` tag.

**2)** `<a href="SomePage.php" target="_blank">Link Name</a>`