# is there any PHP function for open page in new tab

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with action e.g. register.php

I also have a Google group API link -

https://groups.google.com/group/GROUPNAME/boxsubscribe?p=ConfirmExplanation&email=EMAIL_ID&_referer&hl=en

in short... **Is there any PHP function for open page in new tab; on page load...**

Comment: PHP is a server side language. You can accomplish this with javascript/html

Comment: PHP does not open any links in any windows. It just creates script to do those things.

Comment: Unless you use PHP as client-side script, no there is not.

Comment: Simple answer like we all answered in this post: `No there is no such PHP function`

Answer (score 13):

Use the `target` attribute on your `anchor` tag with the `_blank` value.

**Example:**

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Click Me!</a>
```

Comment: Thanx for reply...
this is html anchor hyper reference 
But I want rto open in new tab on page load, not on click...

Comment: He is expecting through PHP.

Comment: @Ali Impossible. PHP is a server side language.

Comment: Yes it's not possible but you should mention that it's not possible through PHP

Comment: Please don't use `_blank`. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Do_not_use_target_blank or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new/8867079#8867079. You could use: `_newtab`.

Comment: And how do you change this script to open in same/current tab?

Answer (score 12):

You can write JavaScript code in your file .

Put following code in your client side file:

```
<script>

    window.onload = function(){
         window.open(url, "_blank"); // will open new tab on window.onload
    }
</script>
```

using jQuery.ready

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      window.open(url, "_blank"); // will open new tab on document ready
  });
</script>
```

Comment: window.open(url, "_blank");
this code is open page as a pop-up.
But I want to open in new tab insted of new window...

Comment: @user1573254 opening new tab is default behavior. I am using it in my application and it always open an new tab. to Open in new window I have to provide height and width as 3rd param.

Comment: He is expecting through PHP.

Comment: @Ali You can write JavaScript inside PHP generated page

Answer (score 2):

You can use both PHP and javascript. Perform your php codes in the backend and redirect to a php page. On the php page you redirected to add the code below:

```
<?php if(condition_to_check_for){ ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.open('url_goes_here', '_blank');
    </script>

<?  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `target="_blank"` to open a page in a new tab

```
<a href="whatever.php" target="_blank">Opens On Another Tab</a>
```

Or you can simply use a javascript for **onload**

```
<body onload="window.open(url, '_blank');">
```

Comment: window.open(url, "_blank");
this code is open page as a pop-up.
But I want to open in new tab instead of new window...

Comment: @user1573254 it does open in a new tab just accept the pop up, try this `<body onload="window.open('http://www.google.com');" target="_blank">`

Comment: @user1573254 accept the answers you feel right, so that it will help further users to refer

Comment: He is expecting through PHP.

Comment: @Ali Not possible and hence everyone gave an alternative here, any issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick,

```
function OpenInNewTab(url) {

  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

In most cases, this should happen directly in the onclick handler for the link to prevent pop-up blockers, and the default "new window" behavior. You could do it this way, or by adding an event listener to your DOM object.

```
<div onclick="OpenInNewTab();">Something To Click On</div>
```

Comment: He is expecting through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with PHP:

- remove old echoed data from DOM;
- echo some JavaScript to open URL at window.onload;
- die();

```php
function open_in_new_tab($url)
{
    ob_end_clean(); // remove previous echoed data
    echo '<script>window.onload = function() { window.open("' . $url . '", "_blank"); }</script>';
    die; // nothing else to do
}
```