# Attribute target="_newtab" for links

Tags: html, hyperlink, target

What is "`_newtab`" value for target attribute in **HTML** "`a`" tag? I can't find information about the compatibility for browsers.

Does it will work in all modern browsers?

How it will work if in browser option users set to open links in new window and not in new tab?

Does this value is described anywhere in **HTML** standards?

Comment: I don't think `_newtab` exists at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure, whether it is `_new` or `_newtab`?

There is no value called `_newtab` for **target** attribute.

May this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8867079/1671639) gives us a better information,

> Using `target="_new"` is technically invalid according to the
>   specifications, but as far as I know every browser will behave the
>   same way:
>
> - it will search for a tab or window with the context name "_new"  *
>     if a "_new" tab/window is found, then the URL is loaded into it  * if
>     it's not found, a new tab/window is created with the context name
>     "_new", and the URL loaded into it
>
> Note `target="_new"` will behave exactly the same as `target="new"`,
>   and the latter is valid HTML while the former is invalid HTML.

These are possible values for target attribute:  **`_blank, _self, _parent, or _top`**

---

I think what you're trying to refer is [`target-new`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target-new), a **`CSS3` property**.

> The **`target-new`** property specifies whether new destination links should
>   open in a new window or in a new tab of an existing window.

```
target-new:window;  //Opens a link in new window
target-new:tab;   //Open a link in new tab
```

**[Note](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp):** The target-new property is not supported in any of the major browsers.

Comment: The target-new property is not supported in any of the major browsers.