# Required help on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this piece of JavaScript code:

```
 <script language="javascript">
    function editRecord(email){
        window.open('CompleteProfileDisplay.jsp?email='+email);
        f.submit();
    }         
</script>
```

My question is how to hide the email value in address bar while calling `CompleteProfileDisplay.jsp` page through `window.open` function. One more thing `CompleteProfileDisplay.jsp` accepting the email value as `request.getParameter` method. Please help me if anybody is having an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `open()` method takes a second `name` parameter which you can use as the target of a post, so you can create a hidden form with a target, open `about:blank` with a the target name and submit that form.

Or you can have a form that submits to the special '_blank' target which also opens a window. Similarly you programmatically fill and submit the form.

Edit: I said '_new' which is wrong....

Comment: _new is not right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this outline to accomplish your goal:

1. Create a small form within your HTML, with its `action` property set to `CompleteProfileDisplay.jsp`, containing an input field named `email`, with a `target` of `_blank`, and a `method` of `post`.
2. Have your function set the value of the `email` input field of this form to the given email address and submit the form.
3. A popup window will open containing the same results as your original request, but the data (email address) will be submitted as a `POST` request without being visible in the URL.

Like this:

```
 <!-- make sure this form isn't nested with another form in your page -->
 <form action="CompleteProfileDisplay.jsp" target="_blank" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="email" id="hiddenemail" />
 </form>
 <script>
     function editRecord(email){
         var e = document.getElementById('hiddenemail');
         e.value = email;
         e.form.submit();
     }    
 </script>
```

(Your question does not show that you are customizing the popup window's appearance in any way, so I am not considering that in my answer.)