# How to create a url link to connect with another application from my application in wicket

Tags: wicket

In `wicket` how can I move using link in one application to another application. I had my application url like this `http://test.examplefree.com/hellohomepage/details` now I want to create an url link in my application. so that when I click on that link it can go to other application whose url is like `http://test.examplefree.com/statusreport/homepage`. Both the applications have same domain name, but the links are different. And my both applications are on three different servers like dev/test/prod. So I don't want to hard code the entire url, only the part of it, like `/statusreport/homepage` or `/homepage/anyapplication`.

I tried with

html

```
<a href="#" target="_new" wicket:id="externalLink1">Click Me to go to next application</a>
```

java

```
add(new ExternalLink("externalLink1", "/statusreport/homepage", "Click Me"));
```

Comment: Also, please use "_blank" as target. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4964223/461499

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you've done should work. What does it produce in the final HTML ?

Another way is to use `RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(Url.parse("/statusreport/homepage"))`.