# How can I force IE to *not* use compatibility mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have looked through stackoverflow quite a bit and found that the following is the most recommended way to force non-compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

My issue with these answers is that they are all IE 8 & 9 era answers.

Is this **still** the way to force to the latest browser that the user is running?

This is for a public site and our users often use IE10, IE9, IE7 & IE8 (roughly in that order).
And yes, IE7 use is more common than IE8.

My only constraint for IE8 is that the site be readable.

It is a modern site, and I want whatever browser the user has to not be in compatibility mode.  I know there is a way to specify a browser version, but I'd prefer not to do that with Win10 coming at the end of next month.

If anyone has any info on what Windows 10 will do with this line that would be very useful to know (the new browser is called "Edge").

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

-Chris C.

P.S.
I do have the following as the first line (no spaces) of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I work on the Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge team.

What you provided is the *x-ua-compat* header/meta-tag. It is designed as a hold-over solution to help you move forward and adopt support for modern browsers, without having to immediately take care of modernizing your codebase. It is not meant as a long-term solution for web compatibility.

The best way to give your user the most ideal experience is to first use the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That should be the first thing in your document; nothing should preceed it. From then on, use *valid markup* alone. Check your document for errors, unbalanced tags, redudant tags, etc. Remember, [valid your markup](https://validator.w3.org/) regularly.

Only use the [*x-ua-compat* header/meta-tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you have legacy code that you cannot immediately replace/remove. In these scenarios, it is permissible to put your users in a legacy document mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

The above will put the browser into Internet Explorer 9's Edge Mode, provided that mode exists. In versions of Internet Explorer prior to 9, the latest document mode will be used.

You can also stack these to show favor:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,9,7,8" />
```

But please don't forget my primary message here - the above is meant only as a *temporary* solution. The ultimate goal is to get your document updated with modern code.

Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer's successor, [**does not support document modes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Microsoft Edge will interpret your document like Firefox and Chrome do.

Comment: What about if we have a user with IE11, they have manually set compatibility mode for our website, then we have updated the website and want to force said compatibility setting off. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I find that using only HTML5 doctype and all valid HTML causes IE11 to put me in compability mode with IE7.

Comment: @Nacht How are you confirming that you're in _compat mode_?

Comment: @Sampson Developer Tools

Comment: @Nacht Can you share a page that has the HTML5 doctype, but renders in compat mode? Also, is this IE11 on Windows 10, 8.1, or 7?

Comment: @Sampson IE11 on Windows 7. The HTML5 example from here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Comment: @Nacht Did you copy/paste that code into a file? If so, you might have gotten some invisible characters before the doctype. Can you open your HTML file in https://hexed.it and share a screenshot of what you see?