# How to add a URL to a Chrome Browser Extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-extension

I've created a **Browser Extension for Chrome**. I have added an **HTML Table** to the browser_action.html as a **Popup** as shown below.

[image]

What I want is, when I click on a **Table Cell**, it **should take me to a link**. Different links when clicked on different cells.

This is part of my code :

```
<tr>
<td class="tg-z3w6 hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="http://ew/Environment/Detail?envid=2715"></a>TEST</td>
<td class="tg-ges6">2715</td>
</tr>
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea why? or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Do you want the link to be opened in popup.html or in chrome tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution for my own question.
Create popup.js and link it in the page:

```
<script src="popup.js" ></script>
```

Add the following code to popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        (function () {
            var ln = links[i];
            var location = ln.href;
            ln.onclick = function () {
                chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: location});
            };
        })();
    }
});
```

That's all, links should work after that.

Comment: This works like a charm!! Thank You <3

Answer (score 3):

In your popup.html assuming you are using jquery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
     chrome.tabs.create({url: $(this).attr('href')});
     return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) I couldn't actually get this to work, so I did it without jQuery

Answer (score 1):

`TEST` should be between `<a>`and `</a>`.

Comment: I tried, the URL is also "clickable" but it won't work yet.

Answer (score -1):

it's  so easy you just need to add `target="#"` to your a tag

like

```
<td class="tg-z3w6 hvr-underline-from-center"><a href="http://ew/Environment/Detail?envid=2715" target="#" ></a>TEST</td>
```

Comment: Setting aside whether this will work in an extension, `target="#"` isn't a great idea for any webpage.  You want to use `target="_blank"` or make your target name some semantically meaningful name.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4964130/2336725).