# How can I use span class and href link in php?

Tags: php

I use this code and it works:

```
    if ( in_category( 'videos' )) {
    echo '<span class="corner-tag blue">something else</span>';
}
```

But in this code how can I add an href link?

I try something like this but it didn't work:

```
if ( in_category( 'videos' )) {
        echo '<span class="corner-tag blue" a href="http://google.com">something else</span></a>';
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: why not add the class to the **a**? wrapping it in span adds nothing

Comment: I forgot about that, it's really late here :) Jeff help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need two different tags, one inside the other. for example, you have to open the `<a>` tag and close it inside your `<span>` tag, or vice a versa:

`<span><a></a></span>`:

```
echo '<span class="corner-tag blue"><a href="http://google.com">something else</a></span>';
```

`<a><span></span></a>`:

```
echo '<a href="http://google.com"><span class="corner-tag blue">something else</span></a>';
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com"><span class="corner-tag blue">something else</span></a>

<br/>

<span class="corner-tag blue"><a href="http://google.com">something else</a></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that. It worked but we only had to change something about him:  echo '<a href="http://google.com"><span class="corner-tag blue">something else</span></a>';

Comment: I will accept your answer : You can accept an answer in 9 minutes

Comment: Jeff, when I press click opens a small window named: [about:blank] of google chrome and it didin't load google.

Comment: well that's very strange. I have posted a working snippet of the html for example, and you can see it works either way

Comment: It works now, was my code fault, i have one small question , how can i make to open in new window, it works like html with target = blank ?

Comment: @I.Alex, yes [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new) should be helpful. also, this is really more of a [follow-up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-follow-up-questions), try sticking to [one question per question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308796/is-there-a-way-of-grouping-a-bunch-of-related-question-you-want-to-ask-so-that-a#308834)