# target='_blank' not working in any browser

Tags: php, html

Below is my code for downloading some files from a webpage. 
Everything works fine except `target="_blank"`. This button does nothing even though the link is correct. If I right click and press open in a new tab it works but when i press the button it does nothing.

```
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i+=1;



    $name = $row["filename"];
    $location = "../uploadedfiles/" . $name;
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <p><hr>Name :  <?php echo $row["name"] ?> <br> Contact Details : <?php echo $row["number"] ?><br></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <p>Date Sent: <?php echo date("F d Y--  H:i:s.", filectime($location)) ?><br></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <p><p> <?php echo $i ?> ) <?php echo substr($name, 10) ?> <a href="../uploadedfiles/<?php echo $name; ?>" target='_blank'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>View / Download </button></a></p></p>
    </div>
    <?php }
?>
<hr>
<?php
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: removed the quotes , but still not working @scottevans93

Comment: @scottevans93 that's not related at all, and it will violate HTML standards.

Comment: @scottevans93 quotes are requiredby standard

Comment: @kasunjith unable to recreate the issue: http://jsbin.com/cijosalijo/edit?html,output

Comment: You cannot nest a `<p>` within another `<p>` it's not valid HTML (and doesn't make any semantic sense). I am also unable to reproduce the issue. Is it reproducible on all browsers?

Comment: @kasunjith even with your exact html i cannot reproduce in 3 browsers (safari, chrome, firefox)! https://jsbin.com/jonusi/edit?html,output

Comment: is it because the html code running inside a php while loop ?

Answer (score 3):

The way you have created button within the anchor tag is not one of the best practices to be followed.

Ideally you should do something like this:

```
<a href="../uploadedfiles/<?php echo $name; ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info">View/Download</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also you can use target="_new" instead of target="_blank"

Comment: @A.Onder is it correct ? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new)

Comment: @kasunjith you are right. _blank is correct. My apologies.