# What does class="target" do in <button class="target"> Like</button>?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a bootstrap button. What does class"target" do here?

Like

Additionally, I tried searching for it on DevDocs|CSS Documentation as well as MSDN|CSS but couldn't find it anywhere. What's the correct way to look for such class attributes. Isn't this a class attribute?

Comment: Put the code in your question's body, not title.

Comment: Bootstrap has no target class that I'm aware of. And is your question "What does class=“target” do in <button class=“target”> Like</button>?", "What's the correct way to look for such class attributes?" or "Isn't this a class attribute?" One question per question please.

Comment: Where did you see to use target?

Comment: I found it on Free Code Camp.

Comment: To answer your other question, no it's not a class attribute. But `class` is an attribute of `button`. In this case, it's value is `target`.

Comment: And to answer your middle question, http://getbootstrap.com is the official place to see bootstrap class documentation, but as mentioned by others, I don't believe that's a bootstrap class. It is probably a custom class name.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII P, Thanks. It is from a code snippet on Free Code Camp. But Target class has not been declared anywhere there.

Comment: I would like to mention one other thing that might be confusing to a newcomer, and that there exists an `a` attribute called [`target`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4964130/4233593) which is totally different than this case.

Comment: The Like in your question title is so confusing.  I didn't recognize it as part of the code.

Comment: The page said: "Not every class needs to have corresponding CSS. Sometimes we create classes just for the purpose of selecting these elements more easily using jQuery." Since there is no class specific to bootstrap that is called 'target', i believe they are saying:"lets give all our stuff its own class name to easily select all these elements,,,we'll name it anything we want but for this case we'll name it 'target'". It was confusing how they phrased it in relation to the lessons, but it seems they r just using a normal non-bootstrap class.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic HTML 101, it is a [CSS class identifier](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp). While Bootstrap defines a bunch of CSS classes, I don't believe "target" is one of them so it's likely whatever example you pulled it from uses it for some other purpose.

The page should have a `<style>` section or link to a CSS file which defines what elements with the "target" class should appear like. It's also possible it's tagged with the target class for jquery selection.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we create classes just for the purpose of selecting these elements more easily using jQuery or javaScript. I think the `class= "Target"` was created for that purpose only.