# Can't open new tabs or windows beyond the first on IE, Edge, Safari

Tags: html, internet-explorer, safari, microsoft-edge, target

I'm currently having an issue where I have three major links on this landing / splash page (http://dairyberries.com/) where it's supposed to link out to a new browser tab or window when you click on any of the three main links under the logo. I've used target="_blank" and target="_new" and in both cases on Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge and Safari, they open the first window but any additional clicks only loads the new site in the same browser window instead of opening yet another new window or tab.

What should happen, and seems to in both Chrome and Firefox, is that if I clicked on all three links, I should see three new browser windows. Not one.

Is there a way around this? Or just a FOL because of browser behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target="_new"` is not an actual keyword for the target attribute in HTML5. All you are doing is telling the browser to open a new window. If you did `target="_qwerty"` you would get the same result.

When you click on one of these links the browser opens a window that it names "new". Therefore when you click on the next link with `target="new"` it opens it on the same "new" tab.

Applying `target="_blank"` to the link will provide the behavior you are looking for. I just tested it on your site in Microsoft Edge and it seems to be working fine.

Here is a good answer explaining the issue with `target="_new"` and why it isn't consistent between browsers:

[target="_blank" vs. target="_new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new)

Comment: Actually, I started with target="_blank" and it didn't open new windows each time. I just opened a new window the first time and then would place the next site clicked inside the same window.

Comment: @AdamBell I see you have updated your site now. It works for me in both Chrome and Edge now you have added `target="_blank"` Is it working for you?

Comment: It seems to be for me as well. I'm a Mac guy but Safari was experiencing the same issues and the problem does seem to have gone away. Thanks.