# Target specific tab (amazon affiliate)

Tags: html

Way too many tabs!

I have a online website and affiliate with amazon. I have many product links to Amazon (image versus text; targeted to the specific products on amazon). When visitor clicks on a product image (my site) it opens a new tab and for each additional product image clicked, more tabs open. It will really distract buyers who want to purchase more than one items.

I believe this question has been posed around but I can't find if here is a clean solution. I would like to have the following occur and any guidance would be appreciated". (note- As of now my links for a new tab to open so my site is remains up and viewable:

1) on a first link click, a new tab opens to the product page where the viewer can log into their Amazon account and shopping cart. I will call this newly opened Tab B
2) any subsequent link clicks from my site are targeted to Tab B, essentially refreshing Tab B.

It appears Amazon can track so I am expecting that even when Tab B is refreshed the visitor remains logged into their account and shopping cart!????

I use WIX for my site development...no haters now as I am not a coder!

I am not a coder and as such not the sharpest tool in the shed. That said I can figure code when I see it, if that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you fully, but try using the target attribute of the `a`  (linke) element? For example `<a href="myurl" target="amazon">Link</a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [target="\_blank" vs. target="\_new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new)

Comment: I looked at the code I copy down from Amazon and it already includes the target="blank" I wonder if this is so they force a dedicated page to validate and track. Thanks and have a awesome new year!

Answer (score 0):

Set the target to a name or "blank" like this example.  Then on each link just make sure you reference the name target name.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">Google</a>
```

That will open a new tab and continually use the same tab on additional clicks.

See here for more info on HTML a tags.

https://html.com/attributes/a-target/

Comment: This will open a new tab, but it will open a new one with every click

Comment: No, only "_blank" would.  blank is just a name for a target frame.